# How to obtain accumulated counts of past events by time $t$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functions, stochastic-processes

Given $f: [0, \infty) \to \{0,1\}$, $f(t)$ represents whether there is an event occurring at time $t$.

How can we obtain $g: [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{N}_0$ so that $g(t)$ represents the number of events that have occurred by time $t$?

I can't figure out how to accumulate $f(s)$ over $s \in [0,t]$, by integral or something else.

Or I may be satisfied with expressing $g$ as any mathematical expression in terms of $f$.

This is one way to build a counting process. But I have abstracted the question to be purely a real function problem, independent of stochastic processes.

Thanks.

Comment: Technically, $\sum_{s \in [0,t]} f(s)$ can be formulated in a way that makes sense, since $f$ is a nonnegative function. But this is not usually what you want to do; usually you want to introduce random times for the events and add up only terms corresponding to those times. (This is analogous to the decomposition of a continuous time, countably infinite state space Markov chain into a jump chain and holding time variables, except without the hypotheses that make the process Markov.)

Comment: Thanks. Can you formulate what you mean by "introduce random times for the events and add up only terms corresponding to those times"?

Comment: A simple example: you have a Poisson process. I'll assume it's Markov. This means that you have jumps of size $1$ at times $\tau_1 < \tau_2 < \dots$, which are random (and, by the Markov assumption, $\tau_{i+1}-\tau_i$ are iid). Then the process is given by $X(t)=\sum_{i : \tau_i \leq t} 1$. The examples I've seen are all basically of this character.

Comment: can you represent $\tau_i$ in terms of my $f$? How about $g(t) = |\{s \in [0,t], f(s) = 1\}|$? Is this or yours a more elegant way than some integral or sum if exists? (I guess no)

Comment: They're essentially the same, just different ways of writing the same things.